# Openfire installation profile set up error

Tags: openfire

After installation of openfire version 4.6 I was able to access console in browse http://domain:9090
and database also imported in mysql but when come to profile set up I am facing this error:
url: http://domain:9090/setup/setup-profile-settings.jsp

A failure occurred while fetching your session from the server. This is typically a cookie issue. Please either clear all cookies for this domain or try this URL again from an incognito browser session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was nothing but restart openfire and follow again. There will be no error.